PSA: Please don't post a multitude of link-only answers with url-shortener links
We recently had a new user post eight answers in a short amount of time. They all linked to a website obfuscated by the same shortener url, and didn't provide much explanation what they were linking to. We got multiple flags for these answers pointing these out as 'linking to malware'.
As I was at work, I was not about to click that shortened URL and instead put the link into a malware checker. It came up as malicious, so I deleted the user altogether.
Please note:

Link-only answers are low-quality.
Please include the gist of what you're linking to in your post. We collect questions and answers, not questions and links. Answers that don't include sufficient explanation get removed.
Linking to the same site eight times in a very brief time is a usual spammer pattern.
If your answer is applicable to multiple topics, please instead write one comprehensive answer and flag the other questions as duplicates.
URL-shorteners are highly deprecated.
Do not use URL shorteners on Bitcoin.SE. Use the actual link so that people can assess what they're being pointed at.

